How to pass the path of a particular file to a unity game
(First of all, I wrote using a translator, so I'm sorry if the sentence is weird)
Hello! Do you know the game called Osu!? Osu is a rhythm game, and Osu can download and play the user's own bitmap. I want to make a game like Osu! using Unity, but I've had a few issues. Please help When you open the bitmap of Osu!, if the game is not running, let the game run and then parse the bitmap. If the game doesn't run when you open the bitmap of Osu!, run the game and then parse the bitmap. If the game is running, focus on the game screen and process the bitmap I want to make it this way I want to create a custom compressed file (e.g. BeatMap.MyRhythmGame) with information about the bitmap, and when I open the bitmap file, I want to run the game like Osu and then parse the bitmap or focus the game screen and process the bitmap
I asked ChatGPT, and it instructed me to add a custom file to the Windows registry. After adding the custom file to the registry, my game actually launched when I opened a bitmap file. It also taught me how to launch the game and parse the bitmap.
string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (args.Length > 1)
{
   string filePath = args[1];
   if (File.Exists(filePath) && Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".myRhythmGame",           System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
       LoadAndInitializeGame(filePath);
   }
}

Thanks to GPT, I solved the number of times the game wasn't running when I opened the bitmap, but I couldn't solve focusing on the game scene and parsing the bitmap when the game was running. I couldn't solve it by the way GPT told me.

I think you are looking for Deep Linking ... otherwise why not simply open a file browser and let the user select a file?

If you're referring to File Extension Associations (like how a .docx automatically opens in Microsoft Word), it's not something natively supported by Unity. As such, you'd have to create solutions for each OS you're building for, or just not support some.
In the case of Windows, associating a certain extension to a file can be done through editing the registry, probably on first boot (Unless you also create an installer program which adds registry keys for the user). After this, opening the file will launch your .exe with the as a command-line argument, which you can get from System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().

Even with this solution, Windows will open a second copy of your application instead of passing it to the first. This means you'd also have to implement a system where the newly created application checks for an already-running app and passes the chosen file to the older application with a custom message, which then shuts itself down. This would have to be somehow added before any Unity code is run, otherwise you'd get a second copy of the game popping up and then closing.

TL;DR: It's OS dependent, and even for just Windows you'd need to add registry keys (either via an installer or on boot), hijack the game engine to check for an existing copy of your game before it starts, as well as passing a message between them. It's not impossible... but I'd definitely suggest just using a file picker.
